# The annotation "@OneToMany" in property was never imported (Doctrine2)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, slim

I'm working with Doctrine 2 as an ORM for Slim 3 but I keep getting stuck in the object mapping section when I try to implement a bidirectional relationship

```php
/**
 * Class Resource
 * @package App
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_id", columns={"user_id"})}))
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserRoles", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="user_role_id")
     */
    protected $user_role;
}

/**
 * Class Resource
 * @package App
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_roles", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_role_id", columns={"user_role_id"})}))
 */
class UserRoles
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="user_role")
     */
    protected $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

I get an exception when I try `php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force`

The output is:

> [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException][Semantical Error] The annotation "@OneToMany" in property App\Entity\UserRoles::$users was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

Comment: I have removed the setters and the getters and respective fields due to stackoverflow constraint of code to text ratio

Comment: It is "@ORM\OneToMany". See your `use` statements for details.

Comment: What @AlexBlex said. You are also missing ``@ORM\`` for ``ManyToOne`` and ``JoinColumn``

Comment: i have `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` on the users class

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Doctrine classes like

- Column
- Entity
- JoinColumn
- ManyToMany
- ManyToOne
- OneToMany
- OneToOne
- [Full list available on Github](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/tree/HEAD/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping)

are part of the `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` namespace.

You should import this namespace with ORM as an alias. Then you should add `@ORM` in front of these classes as annotation to make them work.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(...)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(...)
 */
```

If you just want to use every single of those classes you have to import each separately.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToOne;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(...)
 * @JoinColumn(...)
 */
```

Comment: So your question == solution?

Comment: Do you have the use statement on top of your Entitys?

Comment: yes i have and the error now is 

`[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                            
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Column" in property App\Entity\User::$c  
  reated was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement fo  
  r this annotation?`

Comment: Column is in the same namespace i mentioned above, add an additional `ORM` in front of this and other similar propertys.

Comment: this is how i'm using the `Column` class `@ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")`

Comment: i had missed one Column.. Thanks